# Rspec testing controller user won't stay signed in

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I have 2 tests I'm trying to run and I need to be signed in.

```
RSpec.describe MealsController, type: :controller do

    before(:all) do 
        Location.create! name: 'test'
        @user = create(:user, :admin)
        @client1 = create(:client, user_id: @user.id)
        @client2 = create(:client)
        login_as @user, scope: :user
    end

    describe "GET index" do 
        it 'expects successfull index load' do
            get :index
            expect(response.status).to eq(200)
        end

        it 'expects order to be' do
            get :index, {:params => { :client_id => @client2.id }}
            expect(session[:orderClient]).to eq(@client2.id)
        end
    end
end
```

The first test succeeds, but the second fails with the response:

```
Failure/Error: redirect_to new_user_session_path, notice: "You must be signed in to access this page."
```

I don't understand why `get :index` works in the first test but not the second.  I've tried adding the line `login_as @user, scope: :user` to the second test directly and the same error occurs.

Answer (score 0):

`before(:all)` is only run once, at the beginning of your describe block. Try using `before(:each)` instead, which will run before each spec (or `it`).

Or, since it is the default, just `before do`